# Fit inverse gamma distribution to data in R

Tags: r, distribution, curve-fitting, gamma-distribution

Let's say I have a sample that could follow an inverse gamma distribution (see [Empirical PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sECiX.png)).

I would like to estimate the shape parameter alpha and the scale parameter beta with something like `fitdistr`. Is it possible?

I have tried the this solution (following https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31934/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-inverse-gamma-distribution-in-r-or-rpy):

```
f <- function(x, a, b){
  ((b^a)/gamma(a))*((1/x)^(a-1))*exp(-b/x) #PDF Inv. Gamma
}
fitdistr(x, f, list(a=.01, b=.01))
```

but it does not work for me. It says: non-finite finite-difference value [2].

The data can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4n09w1sszcv0ud/data.txt?dl=0 .

Comment: Sharing your sample would be helpful. Have you tried different starting parameter values?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Julius. I have included the function I am using. I also changed the parameters, but another error appears.

Comment: I meant sharing your data. Since you are using the same function that did work for someone else, it is about your data and/or parameters. So, as to help you, we need to see your data.

Comment: Ok. I've already shared the data.

Comment: What are your data? It looks like some one-column decreasing values? Are those just samples to be binned?

Comment: I've quickly binned and plotted your data, nothing like PDF you've shown

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had included other data. Now I have shared the data with which I made the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer. It is as simple as

```
fit = MASS::fitdistr(1/x1, "gamma")
```